# Reduce sql server overhead with group insertion

Tags: sql-server, batch-insert

I have a crawler that fetch documents across web pages. when i receive a page, i immediately insert the content in sql server, (20 insertion per second). this slow down my application and server responsiveness. I thought I could collect 20 item in a group and then insert it using a store procedure with (20*fieldCount).

This reduce the sql server overhead a bit, but i don't know passing 200 parameter to sql server stored procedure doesn't make another overhead. please help me.
is there any better way to minimize the overhead of this frequent insertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Less connection opening

It would be faster even to call the same SP as you have now and call it 20 times in a row. Because you'd only establish a SQL connection once and then push 20 records in. The major overhead being opening and closing a connection.

Comment: can I use WITH RECOMPILE option in my stored procedure to get better performance ?

Comment: No WITH RECOMPLILE will not likely help in this, but rather just the opposite.

Comment: @Ehsan - Does your application not use connection pooling? What is it written in?

Comment: @Martin. Even if you use connection pooling, establishing a connection is not a cheap process. Doing multiple insert on one connection open is still faster than opening pooled connection multiple times.

Comment: I can think of plenty of good reasons for wanting to batch these inserts. How did you come to the conclusion that this overhead would be greater than that posed by doing 20 individual commits for example? I'm not saying you're wrong I just wondered if you could point to any figures on this.

Comment: @Martin: You're right. I was a bit hasty by writing that statement because inserts greatly depend on the insert complexity. It was just a statement based on my experience (no hard measurements done). But I wasn't saying that pooling would take less than 20 inserts. I said that **20 inserts would be faster with one connection (hopefully pooled)** than **20 pooled connection openings with a single insert**.

Answer (score 2):

You can prepare a xml of your data and then pass xml in input parameter of stored procedure. and in stored procedure using `openXml` you can insert data in DB.

Comment: Or table valued parameters in SQL Server 2008 or the bulk insert API.